# Prometheus - Should we create separate counter or should we add label to single counter for distinguish

Tags: prometheus, monitoring

I am new to Prometheus. And need your guidance for below scenario:

I am working on Bot provider product in which customer can come and configure different bot provider like Amazon Lex, Google Dialogue flow or Omilia.

There is a common api, which responds to request of patron. Here it will use the bot configured by the customer to generate the response.

In this we want to capture how many request are made to specific provider over the time.

For this should we create a separate counter for each bot like below or should we use the same counter with labels?

**Single counter with labels:**

bot_success{,providerId="AmazonLex"} 10

bot_success{,providerId="GoogleDialogueflow"} 90

bot_success{,providerId="Omilia"} 14

**Separate counter for each bot:**

bot_success_AmazonLex - 10

bot_success_GoogleDialogueflow - 90

bot_success_Omilia - 14

For separate counter i will need to add an if-else block and increment counter for specific provider and for Single counter, I will be do it in one statement and just pass bot provider in label.

Answer (score 0):

From storage and processing standpoint there is no much difference in those two approaches.

But [recommendations](https://prometheus.io/docs/instrumenting/writing_exporters/#metrics) on instrumenting your application with Prometheus metrics contains the following:

> Metric names should never be procedurally generated, except when writing a custom collector or exporter.

Consider following: if you plan to aggregate over all providers (for example, for total or average number of requests regardless of provider), approach with separate metrics will require queries like `sum({__name__ =~ "bot_success_.+"})`, and it's generally advised against of. And you'd like to aggregate over provider and some other label, you'll need to extract provider from the metrics name first, and only then proceed with aggregation.

---

Additionally, I would recommend you to checkout [best practices in the metric naming](https://prometheus.io/docs/practices/naming/#metric-names). For example, your metric most likely will end up being a counter, thus its name should be something like `bot_api_requests_total`.